# Jquery prototype conflict IE7 and 9 already using noConflict()

Tags: jquery, magento, prototype, internet-explorer-7

I am using noConflict() function within a template page on a Magento site and I'm pretty sure my code is in the correct order on the following page (view page source): http://animalnecessity.com/company/where-to-buy. The script is working on all major browsers except for IE7 the clickable maps do not show up at all and in IE9 you cannot click on the maps. I am receiving the following error in IE7: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number where-to-buy, line 245 character 4 which is pointing to the second to last line of this block:

```
J(function(J){      
    J('#map-usa').cssMap({          
        'size' : 960,           
        'tooltips' : 'floating',            
        'cities': false,                    
    });     
});
```

Comment: Extra comma. fix it! IE is strict on extra commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Kevin, you should remove the trailing comma after `cities : false`;

```
J(function(J){       
    J('#map-usa').cssMap(       
        {           
            'size' : 960,           
            'tooltips' : 'floating',            
            'cities': false                  
        }
    );     
});
```

Internet Explorer does not accepts trailing commas when using object-literal notation.

It's best to use a good IDE/editor, most IDE's (if properly configured) will warn you when writing this code.